# XAMPP failed to open stream: Permission denied error message

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

somehow I am getting this error

> file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/akaunting/.env):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I am trying to connect to a database that i have already created and i am getting the error message mentioned above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "failed to open stream: Permission denied" is a pretty common error you sure you didn't find annything usefull?  Most likely you find solutions containing `chown` or `chmod` assuming your are on linux.

Comment: I tried chmod to 777 but still doesn't work

Comment: chmod -R 775 storage also tried

Comment: can you show your full command have you ran in cmd

Comment: I also tried hard coding the database details in the .env file but still I get the same error

Comment: Can you please try explaining more? Like explaining which system you are using? (obviously windows, but it is worth mentioning) Which version of Laravel are you using? 
Answering questions like the ones above makes it easier for community members to answer your question

Comment: `akaunting username$ sudo chmod -R 775 storage
MacBook-Pro-2:akaunting username$`

Comment: I am using Mac, Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Comment: `file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/akaunting/.env)` ... that doesn't *look* like connecting to a database (MySQL/MariaDB on XAMPP) - that looks like attempting to write to a file called `.env` ?

Comment: it might be that yes at @CD001 so...?

Comment: "I am using Mac, Laravel Framework 5.4.36" Mac also knows linux command's so `chown` and `chmod` should work try running `ls -l` to see the group and right

Comment: So what are you trying to do **exactly**; your question doesn't seem to match up the the error you're getting.

Comment: its not working @RaymondNijland thanks for your contribution

Comment: "try running `ls -l` to see the group and right" and check php `getmygid` function and see if they match..

Comment: @CD001 I am trying to run a web app thats open sourced so for me to be able to do that I need to set up the database, which I did by creating the database just after that step is where I am getting all that